# Update password page in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, passwords

1. I have a classic asp web site but I'm not very good at it. There is a page where users can change their **usernames** and **passwords**. I want to allow users change only the password, not the username. I made some changes on the code but it didn't work.
   The form looks like: [old form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUkC5.png)

I want to make it like: [new form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WojS.png)

```
<%
oldUsername=QS_CLEAR(request.QueryString("s1"))
oldPassword=request.QueryString("s2")
newUsername=QS_CLEAR(request.QueryString("nu"))
newPassword=request.QueryString("np1")
newComfirm=request.QueryString("np2")
if oldUsername="" or oldPassword="" or newUsername="" or newPassword="" or newComfirm="" then
    response.Write("<div id=""hata"">Fill the form correctly.</div>")
elseif QS_CLEAR(newPassword)<>QS_CLEAR(newComfirm) then
    response.Write("<div id=""hata"">New passwords do not match.</div>")
else
    rst.open "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (Type='T') AND (username='"&username&"') and (UserID<>"&ID&")",conn,3,3
    if rst.eof then
        rst.close:rst.open "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID="&session("UserID"),conn,3,3
        if lcase(rst("username"))<>lcase(oldUsername) then
            response.Write("<div id=""hata"">Your username is wrong.</div>")
        elseif encode(lcase(oldUsername)&oldPassword&lcase(mid(cstr(rst("GUID")),2,36)))<>rst("Password")  then
            response.Write("<div id=""hata"">Your password is wrong.</div>")
        else
            GUID=lcase(GetGuid()):password=encode(lcase(oldUsername)&newPassword&GUID)
            rst("Username")=newUsername:rst("Password")=password:rst("GUID")="{"&GUID&"}"
            rst.update
            response.Write("<div id=""basarili"">Your password has changed.</div>")
        end if
    else
        response.Write("<div id=""hata"">You can not choose this username.</div>")
    end if
    rst.close
end if

%>
```

What changes should I make in the code above in order to make it work.

2. And also I want to add the date and time when the password was changed to **PasswordChanged** field in the Users table of my database.

Comment: "but it didn't work" <-- Any errors?

Comment: No action when I click change button

Comment: it makes the operations over GUID

Comment: Is your form submitting ok? i.e. have you been able to trace error at all?

Answer (score 0):

Untested code below:

Have added some comments, please ask if you need more info or if there are any errors

```
<%
'we have only three inputs now,

oldPassword=request.QueryString("s2")
newPassword=request.QueryString("np1")
newComfirm=request.QueryString("np2")

Response.write "oldPassword = " & oldPassword & "<br>";
Response.write "newPassword = " & newPassword & "<br>";
Response.write "newComfirm  = " & newComfirm  & "<br>";

if oldPassword="" or newPassword="" or newComfirm="" then
    response.Write("<div id=""hata"">Fill the form correctly.</div>")
elseif QS_CLEAR(newPassword)<>QS_CLEAR(newComfirm) then
    response.Write("<div id=""hata"">New passwords do not match.</div>")
else
    Dim sql : sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID="&session("UserID")
    Response.write "sql=" & sql & "<br>"
    rst.open sql,conn,3,3
    if NOT rst.EOF
        'check if the old password provided is correct.Use rst("Username") instead of oldUsername
        if encode(lcase(rst("Username"))&oldPassword&lcase(mid(cstr(rst("GUID")),2,36)))<>rst("Password")  then
            response.Write("<div id=""hata"">Your password is wrong.</div>")
        else
            GUID=lcase(GetGuid())
            password=encode(lcase(rst("Username")&newPassword&GUID)
            rst("Password")=password
            rst("GUID")="{"&GUID&"}"
            'add changed date, may need some tweaking for the required format.
            rst("PasswordChanged") = Now 
            rst.update
            response.Write("<div id=""basarili"">Your password has changed.</div>")
        end if
    end if
    rst.close
end if

%>
```